# "My address is T-O-A-S-T" (X-Files S5 E11)

Tags: the-x-files

In "Kill Switch" (S5 E11), when our heroes arrest Invisigoth/Esther Nairn, she refuses to give any name except "Invisigoth," and then says "My address is T-O-A-S-T." What does this mean? Is it a reference to the fact that the shipping crate she was living in just got burnt? I don't understand why she would spell it out, if so, which makes me think it may be a computer joke I'm too young to understand.

Comment: It was a reference to the fact that her shipping container was destroyed.  She spelled out the word "toast" for emphasis, but it doesn't mean anything special.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems to be a reference to her abode (a shipping container) being destroyed in the earlier sequence.

[image]

She spells out the word toast, as in "[to be toast](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-toast)", i.e. to be destroyed.